# How to fowarding email in php keeping orginal 'To' list

Tags: php, email, forwarding

I have a php script running as a cron job to implement forwarding mail to a list of people which is administered from a web site.
This works fine, except that the lists of email in the To (and also cc bcc) lists are lost. Thus the receiver cannot use 'reply all' to send to all the recipients of the original email. Mail lists such as mailman do this so it must be possible.

Note I am just using the simple php 'mail()' function to send.

Comment: Can you post the code in question that's failing to do what you want?

Comment: I can't post code as I don't know how to write code to do what I described. From some more research I am coming to the conclusion that it is not possible with the simple php mail() function. I am looking into using phpMailer connected by SMTP to my mailbox. However it still looks like I must delve into the inner workings to separate what goes in the 'to' header (which I want to come from the original mail) and who it is forwarded to. So any examples of how to do it would be very useful.